# Linux IP monitoring tool

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ip, monitoring

I need to get the IP numbers that are connecting to the EC2 instance then add them to AWS security group as a security group rule. So only those machines will have the permission to connect to instance. I don't need the port number that they're connecting to instance.

I installed iptraf-ng but app is very slow on the instance. Any other suggestions to capture the connecting IP's to instance so I can add them faster to security group rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [VPC Flow logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/flow-logs.html) to monitor the traffic to the VPC (which will include the traffic that is going to the EC2 instance).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I looked it up and filtered the logs at Logs Insights but it is showing too many IP addresses I just need the ones for that application. :(

Comment: @Emir you need to filter for the EC2 instance as a target

Comment: I see. There's still too many communications to app. I don't want to have service disconnections. Probably behind the load balancer in a private vpc would work better.